# Python & WLST / Undeploy Application If Exist (WebLogic)

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, weblogic, wlst

I want to run the `undeploy` only if the application already deployed, if there is no application I'm looking for, I want to pass this part. I think I can do this by first making a list of all applications and then using an if else block if the application exist I'm looking for in this list. But how can I combine WLST and Python for that matter? At the same time, if an error occurs during `undeploy`, I want to print this error in the exception section.

Edit: "I am getting the applicationName parameter from another file. You can also use this parameter.

And as far as I researched, I can find the deployed application list as follows:

```
listAppDeployments = cmo.getAppDeployments()
```

So if `applicationName` is in `listAppDeployments` then `undeploy` should work, otherwise I want to skip this function but I couldn't merge it."

```
def undeploy() :
    try:
        conn()
        edit()
        startEdit()
        print 'Something here...'
        stopApplication(applicationName)
        print 'Something here...'
        print 'Something here...'
        undeploy(applicationName)
        print 'Something here...'
        save()
        activate()
    except:
        print 'Something here...'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for use as part of a CI/CD pipeline?  I had a similar requirement to undeploy an app if deployed, before deploying a new version.  Ended up just running undeploy and ignoring failures if it wasn't already deployed.

Comment: @httPants There are also processes close to the CI/CD pipeline. Actually, this is a very long script and I only shared the part I was having trouble with.